# How do I prove the relationship between these two probability generating functions?

Tags: probability

This is an exercise I've been asked to do from 'Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering', 3rd edition.

> For a non-negative integer random variable $X$, in addition to the probability generating function $\Phi_X (t)$, defined as $\sum_{n} f_n t^n$, it is possible to define the probability generating function
>
> $$\Psi_X (t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n t^n$$
>
> Where $g_n$ is the probability that $X>n$
>
> Prove that $\Phi_X$ and $\Psi_X$ are related by
> $$\Psi_X (t) = \frac{1-\Phi_X (t)}{1-t}$$

This probability stuff is very new to me and I seem to have a bit of trouble with both this and combinatorics. Things that are supposed to be obvious are not obvious to me.

For this problem it's not clear to me how the two generating functions are related. I think I should be able to work out what $g_n$ is but $f_n$ could be anything, right? So, how do I begin?

Please note that I'm not asking for the answer. I have the solution manual and could copy that answer if I needed to. I'd like to understand the concepts more.

Edit:

Thinking about it more it seems that I don't actually understand what a probability generating function is to start off with so I'm going to try to write what I think I do know so maybe others can see where my thinking might be off.

- There is a random variable called X (the meaning of "random" here isn't clear to me)
- The probability that X can take some positive integer value is $f_n$
- The sum of all those probabilities is equal to 1. (There's a 100% chance that it will take some value in its range)
- There probability that it takes a value greater than some integer is $g_n$
- There is a probability generating function that tells you... and this is where I'm stuck. What is the probability generating function supposed to do or tell you? Where does the $t^n$ in the PGF come from? What is t?

Comment: They mean that $f_n$ is the probability that $X=n$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, but how does that relate to the probability that X is greater than n? I mean X can't be both n and greater than n, right?

Comment: $g_n=\sum_{j>n} f_j$

Comment: Hint: $g_{n-1}=f_n+g_{n}$.

Comment: Sorry, the meanings of those last two formula aren't immediately clear to me. Can you say in words what they mean?